# Unable to fit correct lme()

Tags: r, mixed-models

I would like to fit a mixed effect model that allows me to account for unequal variances across different geos. Specifically, I would like to predict `response` as a function of a fixed effect `X` with `geo` as the random effect.

Here are what the data look like:

```
         X      response       geo
1        4      5.521461     other
2        4      5.164786     other
3        4      5.164786     other
4        6      3.401197     other
5        5      4.867534     other
6        4      5.010635     other
```

Unique values for the geo column:

```
[1] "other"                                   "Atlanta-Sandy Springs-Marietta, GA"      "Chicago-Naperville-Joliet, IL-IN-WI"     "Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX"        
[5] "Houston-Sugar Land-Baytown, TX"          "Los Angeles-Long Beach-Santa Ana, CA"    "Miami-Fort Lauderdale-Pompano Beach, FL" "Phoenix-Mesa-Glendale, AZ"
```

Here is the model that I've attempted:

```
> lme0 <- lme(response ~ factor(predictor) , random = ~1|factor(geo), data = HC_hired)
> summary(lme0)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: HC_hired 
       AIC     BIC    logLik
  54770.69 54836.3 -27377.34

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | factor(geo)
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:  0.08689381  0.66802

Fixed effects: response ~ factor(predictor) 
                      Value  Std.Error    DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept)        4.255531 0.04410213 26918 96.49264  0.0000
factor(predictor)2 0.022986 0.03336742 26918  0.68889  0.4909
factor(predictor)3 0.166341 0.03221410 26918  5.16361  0.0000
factor(predictor)4 0.299172 0.03194177 26918  9.36618  0.0000
factor(predictor)5 0.378645 0.03249053 26918 11.65402  0.0000
factor(predictor)6 0.472583 0.03664732 26918 12.89543  0.0000
 Correlation: 
                   (Intr) fct()2 fct()3 fct()4 fct()5
factor(predictor)2 -0.660                            
factor(predictor)3 -0.683  0.903                     
factor(predictor)4 -0.689  0.912  0.945              
factor(predictor)5 -0.679  0.897  0.930  0.940       
factor(predictor)6 -0.603  0.795  0.824  0.832  0.819

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-4.7047458 -0.3424262  0.1883132  0.7045260  2.1949313 

Number of Observations: 26931
Number of Groups: 8
```

My issue is that the output does not specify a random effect for each level of geo. What is the correct model specification to do this? I've tried many permutations of the formula without luck. Any comments on the overall process are also welcome. Many thanks in advance!

---

RESPONSE TO COMMENT (coercing geo to factor does not change output):

> HC_hired$geo <- as.factor(HC_hired$geo)
>   lme0 <- lme(response ~ factor(predictor) , random = ~1|factor(geo), data = HC_hired)
>   summary(lme0)

Comment: Have you tried coercing `geo` to factor before specifying the model?

Comment: Yep, the output is exactly the same. See edit for my method.

Comment: The `ranef,lme` function is useful for extracting random effects from an `lme` object.  If you want to allow variance heterogeneity among the levels of a grouping variable, `varIdent` is very likely what you want.